# Authentication between two different sites using the WordPress login cookie

Tags: users, cookies, authentication

Two different WordPress, two different users, same account and password.

In this case, if the user wants to go to `(A -> B)` the **B** site after logging in to the **A** site, the session `HASH` is already stored in the browser.

### `wordpress_logged_in_ [hash]` identifier

In this case, can't I log in to the **B** site for the same person? Is this possible?

Comment: Do both sites use the same salts? (defined in wp-config.php, you can [generate them here](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/))

Comment: _do the two sites use the same user tables?_ If they do not use the same user table then this is impossible. Are you sure you wouldn't prefer to use a multisite install?

Comment: Try using AuthAPI and set session for that user again in Website B

Comment: Are they subdomains of the same domain? If not you probably can't set a single cookie for both sites anyway, but there are ways to work around that e.g. StackExchange uses a separate domain stackauth.com for shared authentication cookies I think.

Comment: @TomJNowell How can I use the same user tables? So can a site connect to different tables for wp_post and wp_users?

Comment: @Rup This is actually true. But it looks quite complicated. I have no idea how I can do it.

Comment: If the two installs use different domains then the answer is no, it cannot be done, but you haven't shared enough information to figure that out. Sharing the user tables is also not easy to do, and would mean destroying the users of one of the sites. It also means all the authors of posts and attachments would be incorrect on that site as user IDs would change, it's a destructive change. Shared user tables are rare since it's much much easier to just use a single multisite install. But if your sites are on different domains, doesn't matter, even with the same users, cookies won't allow it

Comment: I understand. This is sad, hopefully in the future it will develop this and have a more flexible structure.